# SearchView Android

Tags: android, searchview

I am new to android and I am trying to create a `SearchView`. I can't figure out why for some reason the 3 lines of code responsible for adding the search manager and providing the search widget make my application crash. Any advice?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);

    // Add SearchWidget
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: please post stacktrace...

Comment: Are you sure your id is "search" in xml ?

Comment: can you post menu/option_menu.xml please?

Comment: option_menu.xml                                                                                                     

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/title_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_image"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>

Comment: @LucienGeorge can you please create new project and use my code and run it, lets see.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Action bar Search - Before Search]

[image: Action bar Search - After Search]

**Menu.xml**

```
<!-- Search Widget -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

**activity_search_results.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java class**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] dataArray = new String[] { "India", "USA", "UK",
            "Srilanka", "Nepal", "Japan" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataArray);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                System.out.println("on text chnge text: " + newText);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                System.out.println("on query submit: " + query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
}
```

**Done**

Comment: searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

This line is crashing the app and I can't figure out why

Comment: @LucienGeorge in my case it works proper. Can you please post logcat ?